# Does a hacker know which IP they hacked?

Tags: attacks, virus, ip, trojan, rat

Suppose someone hacks my computer (by any means, say a virus or trojan like RAT), will they be able to know my IP address in real time? This is about dynamic IP addresses.

Comment: There are commands that you can run on your machine to get a machine's IP, right?

Comment: @schroeder Not aware about that. Could you say more?

Comment: @schroeder Oh yes obviously I can know my own IP address by visiting whatismyipaddress.com. But how does the hacker know my IP address?

Comment: Because the trojan dials 'home' to a central control server to report a successful takeover. How did you think botnets work?

Comment: Say they have remote access to my computer, and if they tried to check it from that website, I would know it (that the website is opening automatically). But any way that they could secretly know my IP?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/165986/windows-command-that-returns-external-ip

Comment: You wouldn't know it, because unless the trojan's writers are spectacularly inept they wouldn't use your actual browser to go to that site -- it's entirely possible to make a https call without opening an entire browser.

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose someone hacks my computer (by any means, say a virus or trojan
> like RAT), will they be able to know my IP address in real time? This
> is about dynamic IP addresses.

Yes,By "hacking" your computer,i am guessing you mean popping a shell on the system,they would know the public/private IP address of the system when they receive the connect back or when they connect to your system by opening your system ports.

Answer (score 2):

An attacker is either going to be directly connecting to a host or receiving a connection back from it; in either case, the system must know which IP address it is talking to by necessity. If the victim is behind a NAT, this address will be their public IP address.

If an attacker is able to run commands on your machine, they could also determine your internal address (e.g. using `ipconfig` on Windows).

Neither way above requires any activity that would be easily detected by the victim.